# Can we conclude that work is being done whenever we see a moving object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

In physics I was asked this question: Can we conclude that work is being done whenever we see a moving object?

Answer (score 1):

No. Work done is reflected in a change in kinetic energy. If a body moves at a constant speed, its kinetic energy $\frac12mv^2$ is constant, so no work is being done. You can say more; not even a body accelerating means work is being done. In circular motion, for example, there is no work done, you need a scalar acceleration to say work was done.